# Generating recursive equation for urn question

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am having really  hard time with stochastic processes.  I will be so glad for your answers. I do not know how to generate the recursive equations.

From an urn containing a white and b black balls, balls are drawn one by one at random according to the following rules:

(i) at any drawing, if the ball drawn is white, then it is returned to the urn,

(ii) if it is black, it is replaced by a white ball (from another collection of balls).

After n such operations, a ball is drawn from the urn. let $W_n$.denote the number of white balls in the urn after the foregoing operations has been repeated n times.

Derive the recursive equation?

ANSWER  is E($W_{n+1}$)=(1-1/(a+b))E($W_{n}$)+1

Comment: Does the urn contain "a white ball" (1) or "$a$ white balls ($a$ many)?

Comment: It contains a many white balls and b many black balls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, compute $P(W_{n+1}=w)$. Notice that total number of balls in the urn always stay unchanged, $a+b$.

We have

$$
P(W_{n+1}=w)=P(W_n=w-1)\left(1-\frac{w-1}{a+b}\right)+P(W_n=w)\frac{w}{a+b}
$$

(you could either have $w$ balls and draw a white ball, or $w-1$ white balls and draw a black one so $1$ gets added)

multiply both sides by $w-1$, we have

$$
wP(W_{n+1}=w)-P(W_{n+1}=w)=(w-1)P(W_n=w-1)-\frac{(w-1)^2}{a+b}P(W_n=w-1)+\frac{w^2-w}{a+b}P(W_n=w) 
$$

Now sum over all possible $w$ (from $0$ to $\infty$)

$$
\mathbb{E}W_{n+1} -1=\mathbb{E}W_n - \frac{1}{a+b}\mathbb{E}W_n^2 + \frac{1}{a+b}\mathbb{E}W_n^2 -\frac{\mathbb{E}W_n}{a+b}
$$

So you get

$$\mathbb{E}W_{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{a+b}\right)\mathbb{E}W_n +1
$$

(of course both expectation and second moment exist in this case, since sample space is finite)

Comment: Thank you very much it helps a lot.